# Does the return value of an abstract method can be of generic type

Tags: java, generics, graph, abstract-class, factory-pattern

the first part of my project is to construct an hypergraph

This is a quickly-drew UML  diagram [image]

The vertex class

```
    public abstract class Vertex <T>{

int vertexId ;
T vertexValue ;

public  abstract <T> T setVertexValue();

    }
```

The imageVertex class

```
   public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, Instance>>{

@Override
public <T> T setVertexValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

I has thought that Type will be inferred automatically as i define it for the imageVertex Map
and later for tagVertex as String

had I  wrongly used the generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've redefined the type T on `setVertexValue`. Use this.

```
public abstract class Vertex <T>{

int vertexId ;
T vertexValue ;

public  abstract T setVertexValue();

}
```

It uses the generic properly

```
public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, String>>
{

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> setVertexValue()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to write:

```
public abstract class Vertex<T> {

    int vertexId;
    T vertexValue;

    public abstract T setVertexValue(); // NOTE: no <T>
}

public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, Instance>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Instance> setVertexValue() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your code, the `<T>` in

```
public abstract <T> T setVertexValue();
```

is a completely separate generic parameter that shadows the `T` in `Vertex<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<T>` for `Vertex.setVertexValue`:

```
public abstract T setVertexValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `setVertexValue()` has a type parameter `<T>` itself; that means it redefines the type parameter `<T>` of your class. Your method declaration should look like

```
public  abstract T setVertexValue();
```

(Note the absence of the `<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this must work for you.

```
public abstract T setVertexValue();
```

Remove `<T>`